# Calling member template<int> function within non-member template<int> function

Tags: c++

I've got this example which compiles under MSVC2015 but not Clang. I'm programming code that I want to run everywhere. I get an "error : expected expression" message. I've searched SO but I can't seem to find this exact same problem.

```
template<int T>
class SomeClass {
public:
    template<int S>
    int Foo()
    {
        return S;
    }
};

template<int X>
void Fun()
{
    SomeClass<X> c;
    c.Foo<0>();
}

int main()
{
    Fun<0>();
}
```

Comment: See the dupe for more detail but you need `c.template Foo<0>();`.

Comment: Wow that was fast. Thank you, that solved my problem

Comment: No problem, the canonical does not have the best title to search for.  Glad you got what you needed.